# WordPress wiki-like plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wiki

I am working on a wordpress website and need to implement a wiki-like function to the site. The requirements for the functionality are:
   - a way to add answers to a question
   - a way to vote up answers you like
   - a way to have a conversation around the answers.

If anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Something similar to StackOverflow? If so Meta has a [list of clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones), you might find useful.

Comment: It is a question better suite for: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [dooWiki](http://doowikis.com) to one of your wordpress pages to achieve wiki-like functionality.